# Graph Lifecycle Notification - What Happens With 404 On Notification URL?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Can someone tell me what the behaviour is when a Graph change notification is attempted to be sent to the configured endpoint (notificationUrl) but the endpoint is unavailable (e.g. your in the process of a release or the endpoint is just not there for a while)?
I can see that I am getting a repeated notification delivery attempt every 5 minutes, but does that eventually stop? Does it become a 'missed' lifecycle event at some stage? Or does it keep trying endlessly?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service will retry for a few hours.

If the notification URL is unresponsive or slow for more than 10% of delivery attempts, notifications will be paused and retried in a couple of hours.

If the notification URL is unresponsive or slow for more than 20% of delivery attempts, notifications will be dropped.

Unresponsive notification URL will not result in a missed lifecycle notifications. Those are only sent when the service was not able to emit notifications due to other reasons.